# Cannot create a model from a preexisting database in Postgresql, .NET provider for postgresql doesn't exist

Tags: linq, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, postgresql, npgsql

I'm having this problem that's blocking me for over 4 days now. 
I'm developing a WCF webservice and tried connecting to my Postgresql database via Visual Studio 2010. I installed Npgsql, EntityFramework, LinqToPostgresql, and also Devart DotConnect for Postgresql, Shaolinq... All that with NugetPackage Manager.
I also installed Entity Developer.

I managed to create a connexion to my Postgresql database, but when I try to create a model out of my database (I add a new Devart Linq to SQL Model item), Postgresql provider doesn't show up in the combobox! Here are some screenshots for more clarification :

[image: Here I add a new item : Devart LINQ to SQL Model]

[image: Creating a model from a database]

[image: Set up connexion properties]

Here in the provider combobox I only get 3 choices :

**.NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5**

**.NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0**

**.NET Framework Data Provider for Sql Server**

Here's a screenshot to the references added to my project :

[image: References]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: X-posted at http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/143701/12379, http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/98648/7788, http://stackoverflow.com/q/29817499/398670 . (seriously?)

Comment: Yeah sorry desperation does it :) I figured I might get some answers by posting it there. Plus it's related and not off topic. Is something wrong ? It's not redundant, I didn't post the question on SO different times.. GIS Stackexchange and DBA Stackexchange have other specialized audiences.

Comment: Eh, it's not "bad" as such, but if you don't add links between them it wastes everyone's time duplicating follow-up questions, etc

Comment: I see.. Thank u @CraigRinger for the heads up and I apologize :) Didn't know there was a way to link the questions

Comment: Do u happen to have some thoughts on what could be wrong with my issue here?

Comment: Not really, I don't do much with C# and .NET, nPgSQL, etc. I just saw this via the [tag:postgresql] tag.

Comment: Crossposting on SE sites is not allowed. A quick search on [meta.se] will tell you that.  I'd suggest deleting your gis copy, as this is about tooling in Visual Studio, and its lack of (EF? Devart? wut) pgsql support, which is on topic here. This lack isn't surprising. Someone from that community would have to create and release it.  Once you go off the reservation, you rely on others to make your travels easier. Expecting existing tools to work against anything isn't realistic. So if you *really* want to use uncommon stuff (pgsql) you gotta do the hard lifting yourself :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only work-around I managed to apply for the moment is by using Npgsqlcommand directly from my code and connecting to the database.
Can't use my database entities as classes but at least this does the trick, for now.
I still hope someone could enlighten me more about this issue 'cause it seems like there is no solution to it which is frustrating. I was literally on the edge of starting from scratch and re-creating my spatial database in SQL Server.